# How would I add "edit profile" and "blog post" functions to front-end?

Tags: functions, front-end

I'm rather new to Wordpress and I've been looking around for an hour and a bit but cannot find what I'm looking for.

I want to add an "edit profile" button to the author page so the user can edit their personal information and I want to add a "blog post" button where the user can write their blog post, both through the front-end.

I appreciate any help with this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a plugin to your site which provides this feature. It is called [WP User Frontend](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your skills you should create a theme template for this. You have by far the most controll over what you want your users to edit.
You can use this template for the basics. Hope it helps:

```
<?php

global $user_ID, $user_identity, $user_level;

if ($user_ID) {

if($_POST) 

{

    $message = "Your profile updated successfully.";

    $first = $wpdb->escape($_POST['first_name']);

    $last = $wpdb->escape($_POST['last_name']);

    $email = $wpdb->escape($_POST['email']);

    $user_url = $wpdb->escape($_POST['website']);

    $description = $wpdb->escape($_POST['desc']);

    $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['pwd']);

    $confirm_password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['confirm']);



    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'first_name', $first );

    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'last_name', $last );

    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'description', $description );

    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_ID, 'user_url' => $user_url) );



    if(isset($email)) {

        if (preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)){ 

            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_ID, 'user_email' => $email) ) ;

        }

        else { $message = "<div id='error'>Please enter a valid email id.</div>"; }

    }

    if($password) {

        if (strlen($password) < 5 || strlen($password) > 15) {

            $message = "<div id='error'>Password must be 5 to 15 characters in length.</div>";

            }

        //elseif( $password == $confirm_password ) {

        elseif(isset($password) && $password != $confirm_password) {

            $message = "<div class='error'>Password Mismatch</div>";

        } elseif ( isset($password) && !empty($password) ) {

            $update = wp_set_password( $password, $user_ID );

            $message = "<div id='success'>Your profile updated successfully.</div>";

        }

    }



}

}

/*

Template Name: Your account

*/

if ($user_ID) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_ID);

get_header();

?>

<div id="user-interact">

 <div class="indent">

  <div id="respond">

   <h1 class="margin">Edit your account</h1>

   <?php if($_POST) { 

    echo "<div id='result'><div class='message'>".$message."</div></div>";

}

?>

        <form action="" method="post">

        <label>First name:</label><br /><input type="text" name="first_name" class="text" value="<?php echo $user_info->first_name; ?>" maxlength="30" /> <br />

            <label>Last name:</label><br /><input type="text" name="last_name" class="text" value="<?php echo $user_info->last_name; ?>" maxlength="30" /> <br />

            <label>Email address:</label><br /><input type="text" name="email" class="text" value="<?php echo $user_info->user_email; ?>" maxlength="30" /><br />

            <label>Website:</label><br /><input type="text" name="website" class="text" value="<?php echo $user_info->user_url; ?>" maxlength="30" /> <br />

            <label>About yourself:</label><br /><textarea name="desc" class="text" rows="5"><?php echo $user_info->description; ?></textarea> <br />

            <label>Change password</label><br /><input type="password" name="pwd" class="text" maxlength="15" /> <br />

            <label>Retype password</label><br /><input type="password" name="confirm" class="text" maxlength="15" /><br />

            <span class="grey">If you would like to change the password type a new one. Otherwise leave this blank</span>

            <br /><br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />



        </form>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<?php 

get_footer();

}

else { 

$redirect_to = get_bloginfo('url')."/login";//change this to your custom login url

wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);

exit;   

}

?>
```

Create a new PHP page and past this script.
Change this

```
/*

Template Name: Your account

*/
```

part to whatever your needs are and save the page to your server.
Now you can select it while creating a new page.